# Mysql replication undo change master on master host

Tags: mysql, database-replication

i ran change master command on master host that should not be run. (Gave parameteres like master host, master password, bin log filename etc). Can i undo this ? Can i just run reset slave and remove master.host file without stopping mysql? Will it get replicated to the existing slave hosts? because this is a master host that is already replicating to multiple slaves.

please advise
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your master.info file.

for example

if you have my.cnf file saying

```
master-info-file     = master.info
```

than delete, 
`rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/master.inf`o